# Code Coverage when testing c++ code using c#

Tags: c#, c++, unit-testing, dll, code-coverage

Here's the situation:

I am writing unit tests in C# for C# code that calls functions written in C++/CLI which in turn call functions that are written in C++. 
The C++/CLI code and the C++ code are in a different solution than the one the C# code is in.

The unit test runs successfully.

However, it only supplied code coverage analysis for the C# module. The DLL for the C++/CLI code and it's PDB file are both in the same folder as the Unit testing DLL. (The C++ code does not have a DLL, it has a LIB file).

What should I do in order to get code coverage analysis for the C++/CLI and the C++ code?

Comment: You'll need to instrument the native code for coverage `vsinstr.exe -coverage`, and then use `vsperfmon` to capture the coverage while the unit tests are running.  This will get you native-only coverage.

Comment: Thanks, when I try to instrument the native code (.dll file) I get the error: Error VSP1033: The file 'XXX.dll' does not contain a recognized executable image. what should I do to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

If you're referring to Visual Studio's code coverage - it should work with C++.  I think you need to have the C++ source code as part of the solution so that the specific run would add hooks and gather coverage information.

Comment: Thanks, That's exactly what I did (the .dll file and even the .pdb file of the native code are in the same directory with the unit test) but when I run the code coverage analyzer on the unit test it just analyzes the c# code and doesn't mention the native code (it doesn't analyze the native .dll)